# How can i prove that if $x_0$ is a solution then $[x_0]$ is unique?

Tags: equivalence-relations, congruences

$4x\equiv10\pmod6$

I'm not sure what they asking when they say that the equivalence relation of a solution is unique.

Also I was able to find the solution -5 with euclids algorithm, is there a more formal way to do this?
${}{}{}$

Comment: Consider 3x=0 mod 6.  Then 0,2,4,6,8,.... etc. are solutions.  mod 6 these are the three solutions [0] (which represents 0,6,12,18 etc.) [2], and [4].  There are 3 solutions mod 6 so the solutions are not unique.  So the question is asking to show 4x=10 mod 6 has only one solution mod 6.

Comment: ...which isn't the case.  *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

The modulus $6$ is very small, so the solutions can be obtained by inspection.

We find that there are two solutions, $x\equiv 1\pmod{6}$ and $x\equiv 4\pmod{6}$. So the congruence has *more than one* solution modulo $6$. (It has a unique solution modulo $3$.)

*Remark:* If $a$ is relatively prime to $m$, then $ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$ has  unique solution modulo $m$.

If $a$ and $m$ are not relatively prime, and $a$ and $m$, and the congruence $ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$ has a solution, that solution is not unique modulo $m$.

Your example has $a=4$ and $m=6$, and these are not relatively prime.